# Magento 2 API - /default vs. /all vs. /{none}

Tags: magento2, api

I would like to understand what's the difference between those 3 endpoints

https://magento2.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
https://magento2.host/index.php/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token
https://magento2.host/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Create product, scope = **All Store Views (POST/PUT /rest/all/V1/products/:sku)**: Associate product with all websites, as it actually does.

Update product, scope = **All Store Views (POST/PUT /rest/all/V1/products/:sku)**: Preserve product website links; change actual behaviour for this.

Create product, scope = **Default Store (POST/PUT /rest/default/V1/products/:sku)**: Associate product with default store website, as it actually does.

Update product, scope = **Default Store (POST/PUT /rest/default/V1/products/:sku)**: Preserve product website links, as it actually does.;

Comment: So do we use all or default? Single store mode but want same values in admin and front end.

Comment: Most likely source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11324#issuecomment-336585220

Comment: Official documentation: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/gs-web-api-request/#endpoint